# Convert absolute symlink to relative symlink with simple Linux command

Tags: filesystems, symlink

I have a complete sub-filesystem inside a path `/home/user/system` containing the standard Linux structure with directories `/bin`, `/home`, `/root`, `/usr`, `/var`, `/etc`,...

This sub-filesystem contain symbolic links, either relative or absolute. The relative symlinks are just fine, they stay within the sub-filesystem under `/home/user/system`. But absolute symlinks are problematic, as they point to a target outside of the sub-filesystem.

As an example we assume an absolute symlink as follows (seen inside the sub-filesystem):

```
/usr/file1 -> /usr/lib/file1
```

In the overall filesystem we have a link at `/home/user/system/usr/file1` that now point to a file `/usr/lib/file1` outside the sub-filesystem, instead of a file `/home/user/system/usr/lib/file1` *inside* the sub-filesystem.

I would like to have a simple script, preferably a single command line (rsync, chroot, find, ...) that converts every absolute symlink to a relative one.

In the given example, that relative link would become

```
/usr/file1 -> ../usr/lib/file1
```

Comment: For those interested in attempting to solve this Q, here's a 250k rep'd user from SO's attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory. There are several potential solutions in that thread, but each has specific situations that it deals with and others that it doesn't.

Comment: @slm [don't use bash for something when you could use a real language instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7305217/4532996)

Answer (score 30):

With the [`symlinks` utility](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks) by Mark Lord (offered by many distributions; if yours doesn't have it, build it from [source](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks/archive/master.zip)):

```
chroot /home/user/system symlinks -cr .
```

Alternatively, on systems that have a `readlink` command and a `-lname` predicate to `find` (warning: untested code):

```
cd /home/user/system &&
find . -lname '/*' -exec ksh -c '
  for link; do
    target=$(readlink "$link")
    link=${link#./}
    root=${link//+([!\/])/..}; root=${root#/}; root=${root%..}
    rm "$link"
    ln -s "$root${target#/}" "$link"
  done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: This would be a nice solution! However, what does the expression `_ {} +` mean at the end of the find? Also, I get an error `find: paths must precede expression: ksh` which does not seem to make sense (as the path *preceeds* the ksh expression).

Comment: @Alex `_` is `$0` for the shell snippet, and `{} +` is replaced by the list of arguments which become `$1`, `$2`, etc. which `for link; do …` loops over (it's synonymous with `for link in "$@"; do …`). The error from `find` is due to a typo (I somehow managed to type backquotes instead of single quotes around the argument to `-lname`).

Comment: Now the script runs, but does not as expected. Maybe I was not precise enough, I have updated the question.

Comment: @Alex What's the problem? I think the principle is sound, but I may have made some coding mistakes. Did you try `symlinks`? It would solve your problem — that's basically what it was designed for (with the annoyance that you have to run it chrooted ([fakechroot](http://fakechroot.alioth.debian.org/) should do the trick)).

Comment: I strongly perfer a solution working out of the box, without the need to install something additional.

Comment: Also, `symlinks` does not compile out of the box. As I need to be able to run `symlinks` on different computers with a different setup, this will become a real mess.

Comment: `chroot: failed to run command ‘symlinks’: No such file or directory`. Running `symlinks -cr` without `chroot` worked though.

Comment: @Marc.2377 The `symlinks` executable has to be available inside the chroot, not just outside. Move or copy it to the chroot or install it in the chroot.

Comment: `symlinks` is C code full of `strcpy`, `strcat` and fixed-size `PATH_MAX` arrays on the stack. Ick!

Comment: @Kaz That's no worse than the Linux kernel.

Comment: @Marc.2377 Get the source package (it has only one C file), add `-static` to CFLAGS , make clean and make, and you have a statically linked binary (check with `ldd symlinks`) that can be copied to and used standalone in the chroot.

Answer (score 10):

Pure bash & coreutils, changes symlinks to relative without unnecessary `../`s in path:

```
find . -type l | while read l; do
    target="$(realpath "$l")"
    ln -fs "$(realpath --relative-to="$(dirname "$(realpath -s "$l")")" "$target")" "$l"
done
```

You can change:

- `find .` to `find /path/to/directory` to convert symlinks in that directory
- `ln -fs` to `echo ln -fs` for a dry run

Explanation:

- `target="$(realpath "$l")"` - finds absolute path to symlink target
- `ln -fs` - creates symlink (`-s`), forcing (`-f`) rewrite of existing
- `realpath -s "$l"` - finds absolute path to symlink itself
- `dirname "$(realpath -s "$l")"` - finds absolute path to directory containing the symlink
- `realpath --relative-to="$(dirname "$(realpath -s "$l")")" "$target"` - finds path of target relative to symlink, in other words: converts absolute to relative path

Comment: I'd suggest to add an `if` clause to skip broken links.

Comment: Doesn't work. On every link, I get realpath: <path to symlink>: no such file or directory

Comment: Please give this script a name, and then add an example usage of it, with example output.

Comment: Please also replace all unnecessary usages of the lower-case L (`l`) with a name which looks less like the number "one" (`1`). Seeing dollar L (`$l`) is _extremely confusing_ since it looks like dollar one (`$1`), which is used to read a positional input parameter and really throws one off from reading this script properly.

Comment: Nowadays you can also use `ln -sr` to directly create symbolic relative link. Not sure when it arrived, but is on GNU coreutils 8.32.

Comment: Pretty good but fails if the filename of some existing symbolic link contains a line feed. If you're running GNU tools and `bash`, you could probably do `find -print0` and `while read -d $'\0'` and add a lot more escaping to above commands to handle all possible characters in link names.

Answer (score 4):

Transforming absolute in relative links is supported by sshfs which mounts remote directories via ssh.

The command is:
There

```
sudo sshfs <remote_user>@<remote_ip_address>:/ /home/<host_user>/mntpoint/ -o transform_symlinks -o allow_other
```

The command, especially the `<placeholders>`, shall be adapted to the specific environment.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is great, but the `chroot` is only required due to the specific requirement of this question that want to re-interpret differently the symlinks. For those of you that simply want to update absolute symlinks into a relative symlinks (for instance to allow copy/paste of folders without breaking the symlinks), just install the tiny program `symlinks`, and run:

```
symlinks -cr .
```

where `.` is the path of the directory, `r` is for recursive change, and `c` turns asbolute symlinks into normal symlinks. Without any option, it will list the absolute symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -lname "$PWD/*" | while read link ;do  
   target=$(readlink $link);
   relative_target=$(realpath $target --relative-to=$link/.. --no-symlinks --canonicalize-missing);
   ln --force --symbolic --no-target-directory $relative_target $link
done
```

`"$PWD/*"` stands to convert only absolute links which point inside current workdir

Comment: Pretty good but fails if the filename of some existing symbolic link contains a line feed or a space. If you're running GNU tools and `bash`, you could probably do `find -print0` and `while read -d $'\0'` and add a lot more escaping to above commands to handle all characters in link names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure sh solution.

```
cd /home/user/system &&
find . -lname '/*' |
while read l ; do
  echo ln -sf $(echo $(echo $l | sed 's|/[^/]*|/..|g')$(readlink $l) | sed 's/.....//') $l
done |
sh
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers seemed to do well without chroot for a fs that was not already root.  I made this shell script that worked well:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ROOTPATH="$1"
shift
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  for LINK in "$@"; do
    ORIG="$(readlink "$LINK")"
    case "$ORIG" in
      /*)
      echo fixing $LINK '->' $ORIG
      NEWDEST="$(realpath --relative-to "$(dirname "${LINK}")" "${ROOTPATH}/${ORIG}")"
      ln -sf "$NEWDEST" "$LINK"
      ;;
    esac
  done
else
  echo Finding and relativizing absolute symlinks under ${ROOTPATH}
  find "$ROOTPATH" -type l -exec "$0" "$ROOTPATH" '{}' +
fi
```

Assuming you saved it as fixlinks.sh:

Usage: ./fixlinks.sh /root/of/path/to/fix