# Finding duplicate files and replace them with symlinks

Tags: symlink, fdupes, duplicate-files

I'm trying to find a way to check inside a given directory for duplicate files (even with different names) and replace them with symlinks pointing to the first occurrence. I've tried with `fdupes` but it just lists those duplicates.
That's the context: I'm customizing an icon theme to my liking, and I've found that many icons, even if they have different names and different locations inside their parent folder, and are used for different purposes, basically are just the same picture. Since applying the same modification twenty or thirty times is redundant when just one is really necessary, I want to keep just one image and symlink all the others.

As an example, if I run `fdupes -r ./` inside the directory `testdir`, it might return to me the following results:

```
./file1.png
./file2.png
./subdir1/anotherfile.png
./subdir1/subdir2/yetanotherfile.png
```

Given this output, I'd like to keep just the file `file1.png`, delete all the others and replace them with symlinks pointing to it, while maintaining all original file names. So `file2.png` will retain its name, but will become a link to `file1.png` instead of being a duplicate.

Those links should not point to an absolute path, but should be relative to the parent `testdir` directory; i.e. `yetanotherfile.png` will be point to `../../file1.png`, not to `/home/testuser/.icons/testdir/file1.png`

I'm interested both in solutions that involve a GUI and CLI. It is not mandatory to use `fdupes` I've cited it because it is a tool that I know, but I'm open to solutions that use other tools as well.

I'm pretty sure that a bash script to handle all of this should not be that difficult to create, but I'm not expert enough to find out how to write it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First; Is there a reason you need to use symlinks and not the usual hardlinks? I am having a hard time understanding the need for symlinks with relative paths. Here is how I would solve this problem:

I think the Debian (Ubuntu) version of fdupes can replace duplicates with hard
links using the `-L` option, but I don't have a Debian installation to verify
this.

If you do not have a version with the `-L` option you can use this tiny bash script I found on [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8722/replace-duplicate-files-by-hardlinks).
Note that this syntax will only work in bash.

```
fdupes -r -1 path | while read line; do master=""; for file in ${line[*]}; do if [ "x${master}" == "x" ]; then master=$file; else ln -f "${master}" "${file}"; fi; done; done
```

The above command will find all duplicate files in "path" and replace them with
hardlinks. You can verify this by running `ls -ilR` and looking at the inode
number. Here is a samle with ten identical files:

```
$ ls -ilR

total 20
3094308 -rw------- 1 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file
3094311 -rw------- 1 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file2
3094312 -rw------- 1 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file3
3094313 -rw------- 1 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file4
3094314 -rw------- 1 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file5
3094315 drwx------ 1 username group 48 Sep 14 17:22 subdirectory

./subdirectory:
total 20
3094316 -rw------- 1 username group 5 Sep 14 17:22 file
3094332 -rw------- 1 username group 5 Sep 14 17:22 file2
3094345 -rw------- 1 username group 5 Sep 14 17:22 file3
3094346 -rw------- 1 username group 5 Sep 14 17:22 file4
3094347 -rw------- 1 username group 5 Sep 14 17:22 file5
```

All the files have separate inode numbers, making them separate files.
Now lets deduplicate them:

```
$ fdupes -r -1 . | while read line; do j="0"; for file in ${line[*]}; do if [ "$j" == "0" ]; then j="1"; else ln -f ${line// .*/} $file; fi; done; done
$ ls -ilR
.:
total 20
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file2
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file3
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file4
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group  5 Sep 14 17:21 file5
3094315 drwx------  1 username group 48 Sep 14 17:24 subdirectory

./subdirectory:
total 20
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group 5 Sep 14 17:21 file
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group 5 Sep 14 17:21 file2
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group 5 Sep 14 17:21 file3
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group 5 Sep 14 17:21 file4
3094308 -rw------- 10 username group 5 Sep 14 17:21 file5
```

The files now all have the same inode number, meaning they all point to the same
physical data on disk.

I hope this solves your problem or at least points you in the right direction!

Comment: I recalled *fdupes* having an option to replace dupes with links, @arnefm but I can't see anything in the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes) nor is it an option in `v1.51` (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS).

Comment: My fork `jdupes` at https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes has the `-L` option which does the desired hard linking of duplicate sets.

Comment: I've just tweaked the script here. It still won't handle spaces, but will handle other special characters (I had URL query strings in files). Also, the `${line//…/}` part wasn't working for me, so I did a cleaner way to get the first "master" file to hardlink.

Comment: Would we need relative softlinks if we're using `rsync` to a different kind of file system? Or if the file system doesn't preserve the hierarchy, e.g. it's a backup server that puts everything under `/«machine-name»/...`? Or if you want to restore from backup? I can't see how hardlinks are going to be preserved here. Relative softlinks would have a better chance of surviving, I might think.

Comment: softlinks could be a requirement if it's to de-duplicate files within a git repo while keeping them in the repo.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't fancy much scripting then I can recommend [rdfind](https://rdfind.pauldreik.se/). Which will scan given directories for duplicate files and replace them with either hard or symbolic links. I've used it for deduplicating my Ruby gems directory with great success. It's available in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for rdfind. `rdfind -makesymlinks true /path/`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar situation, but in my case the symbolic link should point to a relative path so I wrote [this python script](https://gist.github.com/filipenf/e9901883d66b8da65c151cf674e5f2a9) to do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Reads fdupes(-r -1) output and create relative symbolic links for each duplicate
# usage: fdupes -r1 . | ./lndupes.py

import os
from os.path import dirname, relpath, basename, join
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in lines:
    files = line.strip().split(' ')
    first = files[0]
    print "First: %s "% first
    for dup in files[1:]:
        rel = os.path.relpath(dirname(first), dirname(dup))
        print "Linking duplicate: %s to %s" % (dup, join(rel,basename(first)))
        os.unlink(dup)
        os.symlink(join(rel,basename(first)), dup)
```

For each input line ( which is a list of files ) the script splits the file list (whitespace separated), gets the relative path from each file to the first one and then creates the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer given by arnefm (that's been copied all over the internet) does not deal with spaces in file names. I've written a script that deals with spaces in files.

```
#!/bin/bash
fdupes -r -1 CHANGE_THIS_PATH | sed -e 's/\(\w\) /\1|/g' -e 's/|$//' > files
while read line; do
        IFS='|' read -a arr <<< "$line"
        orig=${arr[0]}
        for ((i = 1; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
                file="${arr[$i]}"
                ln -sf "$orig" "$file"
        done 
done < files
```

What this does is find dupes and write them PIPE separated into a file named 'files'.

Then it reads the file back, line by line, into an array, and each element of the array is delimited by the PIPE.

It then iterates over all the non-first elements of the array, replacing the file with a symlink to the first element.

The external file ('files') could be removed, if the fdupes command is executed in a subshell, that's read directly by the while, but this way seems clearer.

Comment: Does this version deal with files with names containing a pipe? I assume neither version handles file names containing newlines, but that's a limitation of fdupes rather than anything else.

Comment: It doesn't, but you can set IFS to whatever you want (also modify the value in the sed replacement), then you shouldn't have any problem (IFS to 'ñ' or something like that should work)

Comment: This creates broken symlinks, and I have files linked to themselves. DO NOT USE

Answer (score 0):

Some caveats up front:

- BASH specific
- No space in file names
- Assumes each line contains 2 files at most.

`fdupes -1r common/base/dir | while read -r -a line ; do ln -sf $(realpath --relative-to ${line[1]} ${line[0]}) ${line[1]}; done`

If more than 2 files are duplicates (e.g. file1 file2 file3) than we need to create a symlink for each pair - treat file1,file2 and file1,file3 as 2 separate cases:

```
if [[ ${#line[@]} -gt 2 ]] ;then 
  ln -sf $(realpath --relative-to ${line[1]} ${line[0]}) ${line[1]} 
  ln -sf $(realpath --relative-to ${line[2]} ${line[0]}) ${line[2]} 
  ...
fi
```

Expending this to automatically handle an arbitrary number of duplicates per line will take a little more effort.

Another approach would be to first create symlinks to absolute paths, then convert them:

```
fdupes -1r /absolute/path/common/base/dir | while read -r -a line ; do ln -sf ${line[0]} ${line[1]}; done
chroot /absolute/path/common/base/dir ; symlinks -cr .
```

This is based on the answer by @Gilles: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100955/77319