# rsync update symlinks pointing to same directory

Tags: rsync, symlink

I want to use `rsync` to make a copy of a folder that contains symlinks to other files in the same folder. Is it possible to get updated symlinks -pointing to absolute paths- in the destination?

I mean, having this in the source folder:

```bsh
source
├── file1
└── subfolder
    └── symlink2file1 -> /absolute/path/to/source/file1
```

I want in the destination folder:

```bsh
destination
├── file1
└── subfolder
    └── symlink2file1 -> /absolute/path/to/destination/file1
```

I need this behaviour because eventually I may remove the source folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to automatically update absolute symlink targets with `rsync`.

A possible solution would be to convert absolute symlinks to relative symlinks in your source folder. You can check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100918/convert-absolute-symlink-to-relative-symlink-with-simple-linux-command) for how to do so.