# rsync links to point on a new destination

Tags: shell-script, rsync

I need to copy directory structure from one place to another. I need to copy only folders and symlinks.

I use command

```
find $SOURCE_PATH/ \( -type l -o -type d \)  -printf "%P\0" | rsync --files-from - --from0 -av  $SOURCE_PATH $USER@$DESTINATION_SERVER:/$DESTINATION_PATH/$SOURCE_PATH
```

Command is successful and it copy folder and links.
My problem is because links point to the old destination.
my source path is **app/cg/dev and**
destination path is **tmp/app/cg/dev**
and now my links which i copied are pointing to app/cg/dev/somefolder .
i need them to point on **tmp**/app/cg/dev/somefolder.

After i rsync all links, good way to correct them would be if i could read link path and than just concatenate my destination path.
example

```
find . -type l | while read l; do
concatenate destination folder and readlink l
done
```

can someone help me write that code?

Comment: Did the original symlinks point to an absolute or relative path?

Comment: @AdminBee  absolute, i rsync that structure, that folders and links are  connected

Comment: Maybe you could [convert absolute symbolic links to relative ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100955/100397) _in the source_ and then recopy?

Comment: @roaima no i cannot do that.  is there maybe option that instead rsync i create new link

Comment: Several of the answers on [that link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100955/100397) I've provided do seem to handle conversion of the symlinks in the manner that you say you need

Comment: @roaima  ok i recreated links on new destination , thanks everyone